# Simple Azure Container Instance but kept getting 'guest RPC failure: failed to mount container root filesystem using overlayfs '

Tags: azure, docker, containers

i am new to azure container instance and just trying to test deploying a well
established image from dockerhub 'datascience-notebook'.

However, i kept getting this error

["start.sh","jupyter lab","--ServerApp.password='sha1:8....72b'"]

Error: Failed to start container dockertestjames, Error response: to create containerd task: failed to mount container storage: guest modify: guest RPC failure: failed to mount container root filesystem using overlayfs /run/gcs/c/aa4f851be9d3da8ee44c062ae03bc67b4c5937c57b83eacebddbe7375f902bdc/rootfs: no such file or directory: unknown

The settings are as such and it show be straight forward...

[image]

Appreciate any help if anyone could enlighten me.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue from Azure as mentioned by ***`PradeepKommaraju-MSFT`*** in this ***[Microsoft Q & A thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/635266/container-instances-are-failing-with-error-34-fail.html)*** :

While ***Azure Product team*** is working on the fix , the workaround for this scenario will be not to provide any command override . Once the Container is deployed you can connect and run the command inside the container.

***I tested the same and it was successful like below :***

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see.. Thanks Ansuman. This is a sucky bug. for example , i cant set a password for my jupyter notebook because of this.

Comment: Thank you, removing command worked for me.